# Does HTML require a newline at the end of the document?

Tags: html, http

In the context of transmitting HTML content via HTTP, is there a requirement that the document end with a newline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, Yes:

> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt
>
> 4.2.2. Conventional Representation of Newlines
>
> SGML specifies that a text entity is a sequence of records, each
> beginning with a record start character and ending with a record end
> character (code positions 10 and 13 respectively) (section 7.6.1,
> "Record Boundaries" in [SGML]).
>
> [MIME] specifies that a body of type `text/*' is a sequence of
> lines,    each terminated by CRLF, that is, octets 13, 10.